# Autocancel a notification when pressing the buttom twice?

Tags: android, notifications

I have this app where you can press a buttom to trigger a notification. The problem is, that if you press it more then once, the notification apperes so often as you have clicked the buttom. Is there any simple code line to avoid that? Something that autocancel the older notifications so there is always just one notification?

Thanks up front!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}


public void sendNotification(View view) {

    switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.buttom1:
            Notification1();
            break;

        case R.id.buttom2:
            Notification2();
            break;


        }
     }



 private void Notification1() {

   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   builder.setAutoCancel(true);
   builder.setContentTitle("BasicNotification");
   builder.setContentText("Test");
   builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon1);

   Notification notification = builder.build();
   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   manager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);

}



private void Notification2() {

   NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
   builder.setAutoCancel(true);
   builder.setContentTitle("BasicNotification");
   builder.setContentText("Test");
   builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon2);

   Notification notification = builder.build();
   NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   manager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);

}
```

}

Comment: `notificationManager.Cancel(notificationId);` use some conditions for hiding notification if exists.

Comment: check my code. i edited it in now. i dont really got a constant id for the buttom

Comment: can we know what is in Notification1 and Notification2. Maybe you can just cancel the notification before creating a new one ?

Comment: they are there. you have to srcoll down abit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a global variable for each notification type :

```
int notofication1Id = 0;
```

When you push new notification store the ID inside the integer variable

```
manager.Cancel(notification1Id);
int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
manager.notify(id, notification);
notification1Id = id;
```

Comment: thanks man! i had a writing error before but now i tried it again and it works fine! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

update:

declare a global variable:

```
int clickcount=0;
```

put this into the method where you perform the Action onClick:

```
 if(clickcount==2)
            {
buttom1.setEnabled(false);

                               }
```

Comment: btn.setEnabled(false); freezes your button. Simply put it after the part where you perform the Action.

Comment: in my case it would be between Notification1; and break; right?

Comment: okay i did but i got an error with the expression "btn." what should i do?

Comment: replace btn with buttom1.

Comment: Again, you want to Trigger a notification when you click a button?

Comment: If your button Name is buttom1 you only have to write buttom1.setEnabled(false); It will be unable to be clicked again. Put it somewhere after the line where you perform the Action.

Comment: no i already got that. but now its like if you press the buttom 2 times, then there are 2 notifications which are exactly the same. thats what i dont want. i want if you press the buttom the second time, the first notitfication gets canceled.

Comment: i dont have an onClick action. the code i put in is everything i have

Comment: But you have a button ?

Comment: Try builder.setEnabled(false); in private void Notification1().